# Why is my imges not displaying using grid?

Tags: reactjs, image, grid

My images are not displayed. Is there anything wrong with my codes, please help me!thank you so much!
This is the link to my code:https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-wilbur-76ssy?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Your are missing return statement:
{imageList.map((image) => {
        return <img src={image.url} alt={image.public_id} />
 })}

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything here:

```
{imageList.map((image) => {
        <img src={image.url} alt={image.public_id} />
 })}
```

Either change it to an implicit return:

```
{imageList.map((image) => (
        <img src={image.url} alt={image.public_id} />
 ))}
```

Or return explicitly:

```
{imageList.map((image) => {
        return <img src={image.url} alt={image.public_id} />
 })}
```